# Control of space in columns of numbers with units in siunitx

Tags: tables, siunitx

The package `siunitx` is great for writing quantity values with units. But I am having difficulty with tables of quantity values. For example,

```latex
\begin{tabular}{
S|
S|
S[table-format=1.9]
}
{Range} & {Readout} & {Uncertainty}  \\ \hline 
10 {mV} &   0.000022 mV  & 0.000069 {mV}\\
100 {mV} &   -0.00001~{mV}  & 0.00011 {mV}\\
1 {V} &   -0.0000007~{V}  & 0.00000029 V\\
10 {V} &   -0.000007~{V}  & 0.0000029 V\\
100 {V} &   -0.000075~{V}  & 0.000058 V\\
\end{tabular}
```

produces this

[image]

The appearance of column two is closest to what I would like (except for the first element which is missing a `~`), but I can't figure out how to reduce the amount of space on the left.

What should I do?

**EDIT**

What I would like to do is control the whitespace without knowing the format (ie, without hand-crafting each column) and I want the units to follow the number (not to be aligned with themselves).

Perhaps this will make my question clearer.

```
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
\sisetup{
    table-space-text-post ={\,mV}, % Enough space for units
}
\begin{tabular}{|
S[table-format=+1.7]|
S[
   table-figures-integer = 1,
   table-figures-decimal = 7, 
   table-sign-mantissa]
|}
{1} & {2}  \\
\hline 
  0.000022\,mV &   0.000022\,mV  \\
 -0.00001\,mV&   -0.00001\,mV  \\
-0.0000007\,V  &   -0.0000007\,V  \\
-0.000007\,V  &   -0.000007\,V  \\
-0.000075\,V &   -0.000075\,V  \\
\end{tabular}
```

This produces column 2 in the form that I would like, but with too much white space on the left.

[image]

The siunitx manual (p 51) says that table-format is a short cut for specifying the different parts of the format, but that did work as I had expected: column 2 above has more white space on the left.

Then I figured out that these two formats are equivalent:

```
S[table-format=+1.7]|
S[   
    table-figures-integer = 1,
    table-figures-decimal = 7, 
    table-sign-mantissa,
    table-number-alignment=center]|
```

However, by default, `table-number-alignment=center-decimal-marker`, which creates extra space because there are many decimal places.

So, I thought that just setting `table-number-alignment=center`, without the other number specifications, would fix my problem, but it doesn't

```
\begin{tabular}{|
S[table-number-alignment=center]|
S[   
    table-figures-integer = 1,
    table-figures-decimal = 7, 
    table-sign-mantissa,
    table-number-alignment=center-decimal-marker]|
}
{1} & {2}  \\
\hline 
  0.000022\,mV &   0.000022\,mV  \\
 -0.00001\,mV&   -0.00001\,mV  \\
-0.0000007\,V  &   -0.0000007\,V  \\
-0.000007\,V  &   -0.000007\,V  \\
-0.000075\,V &   -0.000075\,V  \\
\end{tabular} 
}
```

[image]

Now, the units are overwriting the numbers in column 1!

Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid all guesses about the spacing by using separate columns for the numbers and the units.

I present the table with `booktabs` features, avoiding vertical rules. Below you find a different version, where the data in the second and third column is expressed in millivolts and the unit is in the header: this reduces the number of digits and makes the table more compact and easier to read. You can have the range in volts and the readout in millivolts, there is no problem with this.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  S[table-format=3.0]
  @{\,}
  s[table-unit-alignment=left]
  S[table-format=-1.7,group-four-digits]
  @{\,}
  s[table-unit-alignment=left]
  S[table-format=1.8,group-four-digits]
  @{\,}
  s[table-unit-alignment=left]
  @{}
}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Range} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Readout} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Uncertainty} \\
\midrule
 10 & mV &  0.000022  & mV & 0.000069   & mV \\
100 & mV & -0.00001   & mV & 0.00011    & mV \\
  1 & V  & -0.0000007 & V  & 0.00000029 & V  \\
 10 & V  & -0.000007  & V  & 0.0000029  & V  \\
100 & V  & -0.000075  & V  & 0.000058   & V  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  S[table-format=3.0]
  @{\,}
  s[table-unit-alignment=left]
  S[table-format=-1.6,group-four-digits]
  S[table-format=1.6,group-four-digits]
  @{}
}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Range} & {Readout} & {Uncertainty} \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} & {(\si{mV})} & {(\si{mV})} \\
\midrule
 10 & mV &  0.000022 & 0.000069 \\
100 & mV & -0.00001  & 0.00011  \\
  1 & V  & -0.0007   & 0.00029  \\
 10 & V  & -0.007    & 0.0029   \\
100 & V  & -0.075    & 0.058    \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\sisetup{table-align-text-post=false, table-space-text-post ={\,mV}}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
\begin{tabular}{
S[table-format=2.0]|
S[table-format=-1.6]|
S[table-format=1.9]
}
{Range} & {Readout} & {Uncertainty} \\ \hline
10\,mV & 0.000022\, mV & 0.000069\,mV \\
100\,mV & -0.00001\,mV & 0.00011\,mV \\
1\,V & -0.0000007\,V & 0.00000029\,V\\
10\,V & -0.000007\,V & 0.0000029\,V\\
100\,V & -0.000075\,V & 0.000058\,V\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this provides an acceptable layout, but you need to know the digital format required to choose table-format. I was hoping that I could simply tell siunitx not to put so much white space on the left of the numbers (in my column two). I will add an edit to my post to show what I mean.

Comment: The white space on the left (and on the right) corresponds to the value of \tabcolsep (6pt by default) . You can reduce it with `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{...}`.

Answer (score 1):

With the `booktabs` package and no verticals

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{#1}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{
            s[table-unit-alignment = right]@{\,}s[table-unit-alignment = left]
            S[table-format=1.7]@{\,}s[table-unit-alignment = left]
            S[table-format=1.9]@{\,}s[table-unit-alignment = left]
        }
        \mc{Range}      &           \mc{Readout} & \mc{Uncertainty}  \\ \toprule 
        10         &\mV &   0.000022      &\mV   & 0.000069    &\mV\\
        100        &\mV &   -0.00001      &\mV   & 0.00011     &\mV\\
        1          &\V  &   -0.0000007    &\V    & 0.00000029  &\V\\
        10         &\V  &   -0.000007     &\V    & 0.0000029   &\V\\
        100        &\V   &   -0.000075    &\V    & 0.000058    &\V\\    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```